# How to replace the source of a script tag when a select changes value

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I need some help.

I have two javascript files that run when the page is loaded:

```
    <script id="gvkbjs01" src="GVKB03_files/en_a.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script id="gvkbjs02" src="GVKB03_files/en_b.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

I have a select drop down:

```
            <select lang="en" onchange="loadGVKBJS(this.value)" >
                <option value="" label=" Select a language" selected="selected" />
                <option value="af" label="Afrikaans / Afrikaans" />
                <option value="sq" label="Albanian / shqipe" />
                <option value="am" label="Amharic / አማርኛ" />
                <option value="ar" label="Arabic / العربية" />
                ..........
```

How do I change the javascript source of my two javascript files from the select drop down list that will then call the different js files?

Comment: Will the content of the files replace or add functions or vars? And what part of the URL is variable?

Comment: Take into consideration that you might not want to change the source as the contents will no longer be available although the original code would have already been executed, I don't know how it could affect your result, in any case look at my answer, I show how to insert a new element without affecting the previous one. If you want to remove the existing one look at this post: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Comment: The js files should be replaced.

The part of the URL that is variable is the en_b or en_a.

Comment: You mean they become af_a/af_b and sq_a/sq_b right?

Comment: Yes. The **existing** script file source(s) should be updated/replaced, NOT adding new script files. Adding script files increase the function by one every time a selection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to the dropdown, for Instance 'lang', after create a function that will read the value of the dropdown when it changes, then concatenate the value to generate the source of the file, finally find and replace the source of your old scripts. (I suppose your script tag is in the head).

```
function generateSrc(){

 var lang = document.getElementById('lang').value;
 var src1 = 'GVKB03_files/'+lang+'_a.js';
 var src2 = 'GVKB03_files/'+lang+'_b.js';

 //Replace src from old scripts in head
 var headElms = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].children;
 var found = 0
 for(var i = 0; i < headElms.length; i++) {
    if(headElms[i].tagName == 'SCRIPT') {
           src_name = headElms[i].src;
           if(src_name.search("GVKB03_files") > 0 && found == 0){
             found++;
             headElms[i].src = src;
           }else if(src_name.search("GVKB03_files") > 0 && found == 1){
             headElms[i].src = src2; 
           }
     }
  }

}
```

on Html:

```
<select id="lang" lang="en" onchange="generateSrc()" >
```

Comment: You need to append it to the head too

Comment: Sorry for changing my answer so much, I realized I was missing some steps, document.getElementTagName returns an array so you need to select the first element [0] and then append the new element, please try the code, I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Eddy XP,Thnaks for your response.

Can I change the src of the **existing** js script files:
script id="gvkbjs01" & <script id="gvkbjs02"

from the select?

Comment: Ok @user121774, I see what you mean now, I changed my code in the answer, it will replace the old script sources that match GVKB03_files for the new sources generated from the drop down. Cheers

Comment: Thanks very much that works! Just one more question: **How do I "call" the new js script files by its id, once the src is changed?**

Comment: @user1261774 - What do you mean by "calling"? The new script will be executed automatically after being inserted in the head.